# erorr php and XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml, rss

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 3 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

```html
<?php

//index.php
include '../config.php';
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">';
  echo '<channel>';
echo '<title>janbak RSS Feed</title>';
echo '<link>http://www.janbak.net</link>';
echo '<description>RSS Description</description>';

echo '<language>en-us</language>';
  echo '<lastBuildDate>2021-8-11T04:44:16Z</lastBuildDate>';

  $sql="SELECT * FROM product WHERE adds='yes' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" ;

$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<item>';
         echo '<title>'.$row["tetl"].'</title>';
         echo '<link>https://www.janbak.net/product.php?view='.$row["add_number"].'</link>';
      echo'<guid>'.md5($row["id"]).'</guid>';
         echo '<pubDate>'.date('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT</pubDate>';
         echo '<description>'.$row['wsf'].'</description>';
       echo '<content:encoded>';
          echo '<enclosure url="https://www.janbak.net/panel/uploads_adds/'.$row["img"].'" />';
echo '</item>';
  }}
    
  echo '</channel>';

echo '</rss></xml>';?>
```

Comment: I would recommend not trying to hand build XML content as it can be prone to errors (not the ones causing this problem though).  There are a couple of useful libraries in PHP to help with this and it's worth learning at least 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is inherent to how XML is output via PHP and interpreted by your browser and it is not specific to the module. Googling it yields two causes: whitespace before the opening PHP tag or whitespace after the closing PHP tag. To fix it, make sure all files and all included files (attached via the include/require statement or via the use statement) do not have whitespace before the opening PHP tag and do not have the closing PHP tag at all, as it is obsolete.